# Codeiginter set style on flashdata? How? Possible?

Tags: css, codeigniter

Is it possible to set css-style at flashdata when printing it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is simple: yes

[Here is a sparks](http://getsparks.org/packages/flash_message/versions/HEAD/show) that wraps all the flash data functionality into a great message system, including css styling.

Basically you can modify the flashdata output, so whenever you output 'flashdata' you can include a `<div class="flash">` and `</div>` on either side.

Then just style the flash css style however you desire.

Comment: Please make the answer more "self-contained".  Perhaps, briefly explain the simply concept.